# Multithreaded c program design help

Tags: c, multithreading

I don't have much experience with multithreading and I'm writing a c program which I believe is suited to running in two threads. The program will listen on the serial port for data, read and process new data when it's available, and publish the newest processed data to other (irrelevant) modules via a third party [IPC api](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~IPC/) (it's confusingly named IPC) when requested.

In order to receive the request to publish data via IPC, the program must call IPC_listenwait(wait_time);. Then if a request to publish is received while "listenwaiting" a handler is invoked to publish the newest data.

One option is to do this in one thread like:

```
for(;;) {
  read_serial(inputBuffer);
  process_data(inputBuffer, processedData); //Process and store
  IPC_listenwait(wait_time); //If a request to publish is received during this, 
}                            //then a handler will be invoked and the newest piece of        
                             //processedData will be published to other modules

publishRequestHandler() { //Invoked when a message is received during IPC_listenwait
  IPC_publish(newest(processedData));
}
```

And this works, but for the application it is important that the program is very responsive to the request to publish new data, and that the data published is the newest available. These goals are not satisfied with the above because data may arrive after the process begins listenwaiting and before a request to publish message is received. Or the process may be reading/processing when a request to publish message is incoming, but won't be able to service it until the next IPC_listenwait call.

The only design I can think of is to have one thread to read, which will just do something like:

```
readThread() {
    for(;;) { //pseudocode
      select();
      read(inputBuffer);
      process(inputBuffer, processedData);
    }
}
```

And have the main thread just listening for incoming messages:

```
mainThread() {
  IPC_listenwait(forever);
}

publishRequestHandler() { //Invoked when a message is received during IPC_listenwait
  IPC_publish(newest(processedData));
}
```

Is this the design you would use? If so, will I need to use a semaphore when accessing or writing processedData?

Will this give me good responsiveness?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You're mostly on the right track.

The one thing you have to watch out for is concurrent access to the publishable data, because you don't want one thread clobbering it while another is trying to read it.  To prevent that, use a pair of buffers and a mutex-protected pointer to whichever one is considered current.  When `process_data()` has something ready, it should dump its results in the non-current buffer, lock the pointer mutex, repoint the pointer to the buffer containing the new data and then release the mutex.  Similarly, the publisher should lock the pointer mutex while it reads the current data, which will force anything that might want to clobber it to wait.  This is a bit more complex than having a single, mutex-protected buffer but will assure that you always have something current to publish while new data is being prepared.

If your processing step takes long enough that you could get multiple sets of data to read, you might split the read/process thread into two and let the reader make sure the processor only ever gets the latest and greatest so you don't end up processing stuff you won't ever publish.

Excellent first question, by the way.  Have an upvote.

Comment: Ahh, the two buffers solution is simple but genius! Thanks